# Is there a minimal first-order model that has IP theory?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

I'm hoping to (prove that one cannot) find an infinite first-order $\mathcal{M}$ that is:

- Minimal (All definable subsets of $\mathcal{M}$ are finite or cofinite)
- IP (has the independence property)

Any such model would only have arbitrarily large, finite, pairs of tuples $(a_i)_{i<n}$ and $(b_i)_{i\subseteq n}$ for any formula witnessing the IP.

Comment: If there is a sequence of homogeneous graphs with the property that any infinite ultraproduct of them has IP, then I think you can build an example. The random graph is pseudo-finite, but I don't know it can be written like this.

Comment: @JamesHanson in my previous comment, I missed the word "homogeneous". Don't you just need vertex-transitivity? I think the disjoint union of the [Paley graphs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley_graph) works.

Comment: @AlexKruckman You're right. I was using the wrong term. You just need that there's only one $1$-type, which is vertex-transitivity in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the universal theory of "disjoint unions of boolean algebras", that is, a model of the theory is given by a set $I$ and a boolean algebra $B_i$ for every $i \in I$ and an embedding of structures is an embedding $I \hookrightarrow J$ of sets together with an embedding $B_i \hookrightarrow B_j$ of boolean algebras. Thus it has two sorts $X$ and $I$ together with a surjective map $X \to I$ such that each fiber carries the structure of a boolean algebra with no relation between the fibers.

There is a model $A$ of this theory with the property that $I$ is the set of natural numbers and each $B_i$ is a boolean algebra of size $2^i$; the $B_i$, and hence $A$, are uniquely determined up to isomorphism.

In this structure the set $I$ is stably embedded and essentially just an infinite set with some named elements. Namely in a saturated model each $B_i$ is either finite or else a saturated atomless boolean algebra, so if the fibers above $i,j \in I$ are both infinite then the $B_i$ and $B_j$ are isomorphic, so $i$ and $j$ are conjugate by an automorphism of the whole structure.

To finish we must only note:

1. The structure $A$ is minimal: the induced structure on $I$ is strongly minimal so given a definable set either the projection to $I$ is cofinite or its complement is. Since the fibers of $I$ are finite, it follows that every definable set is finite or cofinite.
2. But $A$ does not have the NIP: in a saturated model there is a copy of an infinite atomless boolean algebra, and these do not have the NIP

Comment: Why can't you define the set of all bottom elements? Isn't that infinite and co-infinite?

Comment: There is a way to 'forget where the bottom is' in a Boolean algebra, which I think would make this example work. You need all of the fibers to be homogeneous, so that you can't select out a preferred element in infinitely many of them.

Also, in bigger models of this theory, the new Boolean alegbras will be atomic, not atomless. This isn't an issue for the example working, but it's worth pointing out.

Comment: You are right. This is actually precisely the kind of example suggest in your original comment, except it does not work because the fibers are not homogenous!